# Submit form that has a javascript submit script

Tags: python

Is there anyway to submit this in python? 
(Without forming my own url request and without using mechanize session, or selenium?)

```
<form id="theform" action="../login.asp?tx=" method="post">
   <input type=hidden name=E8IyqHS value='kgDcZHY+nV' >
   <input type=hidden name=DDSddfD value='KFSJXPH6De' >
   <input type=hidden name=AaaiJMK value='' >
   <input type=hidden name=pGmyGYt value='Ozz9WrvjYO' >
   <input type=hidden name=On3OTo9 value='wlAzaxtdwN' >
```

+ about 50 more input boxes

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      document.getElementById('theform').submit();
   </script>
</form>
```

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use selenium?

Comment: I'm trying to write something that can run in the background while users work on other tasks. Selenium pops up a window.  I've ended up going with Selenium for the time being.

Comment: to run selenium in the background, use Webdriver with PhantomJs (http://phantomjs.org/) It's a well working browser that doesn't have to execute any browser or render visible pages.